# How to build this SQL summary?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
a project has_many tasks
a task can be assigned to many members
```

For example:

```
Project   Task  Member
-------   ----  ------
   P1      T1     M1
   P1      T2     M2
   P2      T1     M1
   P2      T2     M2
   P2      T3     M1
   P3      T1     M2
```

I'd like to get the following summaries, i.e. the last task of a project break down by member:

```
 ------ ---
 T1      3
 - M1    2
 - M2    1
 T2      2
 - M2    2
 T3      1
 - M1    1
```

How to build the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following SQL

```
   select task, null as member, COUNT(*) as count from yourtable group by task
   union
   select task, member, COUNT(*) from yourtable group by task, member
   order by task, member
```